# Angular watch listener on filtered collection called at the wrong time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an interesting problem with watching changes to a filtered collection using AngularJS.

I have a collection of items in my scope which is filtered using one of its properties and rendered using `ng-repeat`:

```
    <input ng-model="searchName" placeholder="search"/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in (filteredItems = (items | filter:searchName))">
            {{i.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to watch changes to `filteredItems`, so that I can update a scope variable which depends on currently visible items. For this example lets say I would like to update a variable keeping the current `filteredItems` length and show it to the user:

```
<p>filtered items length: {{filteredItemsLen}}</p>
```

I registered a listener for `filteredItems` in my controller:

```
$scope.$watch('filteredItems', function(newItems, oldItems) {
    $scope.filteredItemsLen = newItems.length;
}, true);
```

This listener however is not always called in the moment of changes made to `filteredItems`. In the fiddle below, please try this:

1. Put "aa" into the filter input: displayed list gets updated,
   listener *not* called so the length displayed is wrong.
2. Put "aaa" into the filter input: displayed list gets updated,
   listener is called *twice* (first with the data from the previous filter, then with the current data), the length displayed is correct.

Here is the fiddle. Please have a look at the console log to see when the listener is actually called.

http://jsfiddle.net/7QJJK/8/

Interesting observation: if I use `{{filteredItems}}` somewhere on the page, then the listener gets called correctly.

Is there something I don't understand about AngularJS? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure *why* it's doing that but It seems angular is deferring its digest cycle. Unless you want to go into debugging angular itself to find out the cause, I'd suggest two alternative.

In most cases, manual watches are used when you do not want to change something on the scope itself (ie watch for a change and call another function, not modifying the scope). What you want to achieve is closely related to the concept of computed observable, but at the same time, you only return a property from another object without transforming it.

**Use the property directly**

In the template, you can directly use `filteredItems.length`. Because it's a number, angular will achieve stability in the digest cycle even though the underlying array changes.

```
<p>filtered items length: {{filteredItems.length}}</p>
```

**Use a computed property on the scope**

Since `filteredItems` will be on the scope at some point, this is overkill (unless you compute the length and return something different). In the scope, you can define a function that returns a value and angular will happily watch for the changes in its digest cycle:

```
function SomeCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.items = [{name: 'aa'}, {name: 'ab'}, {name: 'ac'}];

    $scope.filteredItemsLen = function() {
        return ($scope.filteredItems || []).length;  
    };

    $scope.$watch('filteredItemsLen()', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('Filtered length changed from ' +
                    oldValue + ' to ' + newValue);
    });
}

<p>filtered items length: {{filteredItemsLen()}}</p>
```

**Edit:** Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QJJK/9/) for the second option

Comment: Returning a length property was just to simplify my case. What I want to achieve is to compute some value based on some properties of the visible entries. The second option that you proposed (computed property) is actually a better approach to this than my watcher.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in Angular 1.1.1 that jsfiddle uses. If you update to 1.1.5, it works as you would expect and $watch runs everytime the number of filtered matches changes - http://jsfiddle.net/7QJJK/10/

Comment: Yes it works with 1.1.5, thanks. In fact all earlier versions of angular have this issue, e.g. stable 1.0.7.